# reference to pointer as argument to single pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understanding why the code below doesn't work. I realize that I'm trying to push a pointer reference to a function and change the value of that address with other new. So  the first pointer pointing to new string. The question is why this working only with double pointer argument?

```
#include <stdio.h>


char new_str[] = "This is a new string";


int change_ptr(char * str_ptr)
{
    *str_ptr = new_str;
}


int main()
{
    char * a_str = "Hello";

    change_ptr(&a_str);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the type of `&a_str` is `char **` and `&a_str` is not passing by reference but you are passing the address of the variable that follows.

Comment: Read the compiler messages

Comment: One is an address-of (`&`) which would necessitate the parameter be of type `char **` in the function `change_ptr`.

Comment: You actually cannot pass sth. by reference in `C` directly. You have to use pointers for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply pass a pointer you only change the data in that pointer. To change where that data is you have to use a pointer to a pointer.

You would have caught this error if you compiled with the `-Wall` flag. Always enable compiler warnings.

In your case, you need to declare your function so that the parameter is a pointer to a pointer:

```
int change_ptr(char ** str_ptr)
{
    *str_ptr = new_str;
}
```

Comment: he _has_ passed a pointer to a pointer - the problem is that the function he's passing it to is only expecting a pointer

Comment: @Alnitak You're right. I didn't catch that until now.